# How to fix Flutter Error: Could not create isolate

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart, android-virtual-device

I am getting this issue when I try to run my flutter app

````
landingpage.dart:1
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/flutter ( 3425): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(143)] Could not prepare isolate.
E/flutter ( 3425): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(385)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter ( 3425): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(604)] Could not launch engine with configuration.```

I have tried running flutter clean but it did not fix the issue. Does anyone know how I could fix it?
````

Answer (score 0):

try

```
flutter clean
```

then

```
flutter run
```

Also check if you have a main.dart in lib folder. If not then create it.

Comment: Not working with this